# How do I make changes to a cell using wxPython DataViewCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython's DataViewCtrl to display some data.  On the first column I am displaying an icon using AppendIconTextColumn.  The problem is that the icon is shifted to the right and the right portion of the icon is cut off.  I have tried using the flag align=ALIGN_LEFT, but that has no affect.

It seems that there should be more options for configuring a cell.  Like changing the background color or aligning images.

Can someone please show me how I can move the icon in the cell?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Haven't used the DVC stuff much, but did you check out the wxPython demo and the doc for it?  E.g.: wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/dataview.DataViewItemAttr.html

Comment: Yea, the documentation sucks.  Anyhow, I have fixed the image getting cut off, but I still have not been able to make it move left.  So I have a large space on the left hand side of the image that looks weird.  Anyone know how I can get it to move left?

Comment: Do you have a small runnable sample which shows the problem?  Wouldn't mind playing with it as I want to get more familiar with the DVC stuff.  Currently I use ObjectListView as DVC was not available at the time.  Re doc, if you have enhancements for it maybe do a PR on https://github.com/RobinD42/Phoenix